# How to get the desired character by split or substring method in stringArray JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is an array and there are strings that are different from each other but contain operations.All of the strings have a large operator and a small operator.I want to separate the characters from the operator and later.

My example Array;

```
[definitions1<=3123,definitions31241>=32414,definitions123213123>=12]
```

The result I want;

```
[<=3123,>=32414,>=12]
```

When i try with split method like this,

(split(<).pop()) or (split(>).pop())

Result = [=3123,=32414,=12]  i could not get (<,>) operator.

When i tried with subStr, I cannot give standard start and finish parameters because strings are different lengths.

I would be glad if someone shows regular expression method or a simpler way.

Comment: "*There is an array and there are strings*" - that doesn't look like an array. Please post your input and output data in valid JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split it with a RegExp with capture group

```js
const strs = ["definitions1<=3123","definitions31241>=32414","definitions123213123>=12"];

const result = strs
  // matches multiple occurrences of "<", "=" and ">"
  // like "<", "<=", "===", ">=", but also "<<=====>>", ">><<"
  .map((x) => x.split(/([<=>]+)/))
  .map(([definition, operator, value]) => [operator, value].join(""));

document.write(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use search to find the index of starting positiong and using string length you can slice the string.

```
var str = "definitions1<=3123"; 
var m = str.search("<");
var n = str.slice(m,str.length);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: You'll want to use `indexOf` instead of `search` - it's not a regular expression. Also don't forget to check the result for `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr= ['definitions1<=3123','definitions31241>=32414','definitions123213123>=12']

var newarr=arr.map(x=> x.split('='))
 finalarray=[]
newarr.forEach(array => { 
    resu=array[0].includes('<') ?finalarray.push('<='+array[1]):finalarray.push('>='+array[1])

});               
               console.log(finalarray)
```